# Viewport on Mobile/Tablet devices

Tags: iphone, ipad, html, mobile-safari, viewport

I wanted to learn and understand what exactly is viewport and also how it affects the overall website layout. Also what is the difference between layout viewport and visual viewport?

Is it related to HTML% in any way?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableViewport.html and at http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/ both of which introduce various aspects of the viewport meta tag, and explain how to use the different viewport properties.